# Python JSON File Formatting

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hello I am trying to create a JSON file, I am having trouble formatting the file.
Below I will provide the code, and the output.

Code:

```
def writeToFile(self):
    self.json_conceivement = os.path.join("./",'NoobPremeNewEggLogIn.json')
    self.accounts = {}
    if os.path.exists(self.json_conceivement):
      try:
          with open(self.json_conceivement) as f:
              self.accounts = dict(json.loads(f.read()))
      except:
          pass
      self.accounts = {}
    else:
      try:
          with open(self.json_conceivement) as f:
              self.accounts = {}
      except:
          pass
      self.accounts['Profiles'] = []
      
  
    self.autoSave()

def autoSave(self):
   with open(self.json_conceivement, "a", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
       json.dump(dict(self.accounts.items()), outfile,ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Output:(if I run it once, expected)

```
{
    "Profiles": []
}
```

Output:(if i run it twice,incorrect)

```
{
    "Profiles": []
}{}
```

Wanted output:

```
{
    "Profiles": [{}]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not opening the file in *a*ppend mode should work.

Comment: You open file with 'append' mode. Thats why you have incorrect json second time you run the script. Change your 'autosave' function.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```py
with open(self.json_conceivement, "a", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
```

to

```py
with open(self.json_conceivement, "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
```

Comment: with this, the second time I run it, it overwrites the data and just writes "{}"

Comment: And what is expected? Profiles is the list? If it is, then empty list should be "[]", if it's object then it should be "{}"

Comment: I have provided the expected output above, I want the "{}" to go inside the "[]".

Comment: I think, that you overrides 'self.accounts = {}' in first IF statement.

Comment: And please, avoid bare excepts. use at least 'except Exception:'

Comment: Without that 'self.accounts = {}' in first IF statement, nothing happens